# refreshing generated code from dbml

Tags: visual-studio, auto-generate, dbml

I've added two new tables to the database.
I've dropped them on the design surface.
My understanding is that it should just automatically generate the design.cs code as a result.
It did, according to my faulty memory, when I added a new table last week, but not this week.

I checked the references in csproj and everything looks OK there.

I tried the RunCustomTool, but that didn't seem to pull anything in to either the DBML or the designer.cs.
No combination of deleting, saving, and re-adding has had any effect.

This is using the MSLinqToSQLGenerator, not SQLMetal
It feels like there is some simple trick I'm missing.

UPDATE: So the problem is with a specific table.
If I add this table, it generates correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_LeakageClass](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Class] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK__LeakageClass] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If I add this table, it quits working and nothing else generates code from then on.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_SeatSize](
    [model] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValveSize] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SeatSize] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Stroke] [int] NOT NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK__SeatSize] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [model] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't handle having a field named similar to the table.
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_SeatSize](`
`[SeatSize] [int] NOT NULL,`
doesn't work.
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_SeatSize](`
`[SeatSizer] [int] NOT NULL,`
works fine. Note that the underscore prefix on the table isn't enough to make a difference.